# Analysis of passed/not passed students by enrolled year

Tags: dataset, statistics, data-analysis, descriptive-statistics

I am analysing some data from my University about successful students through years. The dataset looks like as follows

```
Student     Passed        Enrolled_Year
    A             0                2016
    B             1                2008
    C             1                2008
    D             0                2012
    E             1                2007
    F             1                2019
    G             1                2006
    H             1                2006
    I             0                2012
    L             1                2019
    M             0                2018
    N             1                2008
```

I already plotted the frequency of passed/not passed through years, to see when students, who passed exams.
I would like to know if it makes sense to look at a possible correlation between `Passed` and `Enrolled_Year`, when the number of `Passed` students is small compared to those who not passed.
I would like to get some insights from my dataset:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tUgHoFdzq2vSLHaPzAiNQC5Xkrk2SmKX/view?usp=sharing and one of this was looking at the possible correlation.
I would appreciated it if you could let me know if it makes sense a such analysis with big difference among frequency.

Comment: Did you try a simple thresholding ?

Comment: I extracted an equal number of passed/not passed students, where the not passed where selected randomly. But, of course, it changes the frequency of years.I don't know if you mean that

Comment: You should not change the distribution of the data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, you could use a simple thresholding.

If you have the dataset $S$ where an element has the form $(x,y,c) \in S$, $x$ denotes the year,  $y$ is a binary value (exam passed or not), and $c$ is the student id.

you can obtain a classifier by using
$\{(x,y,c) \in S \mid x \leq \theta\}$ and $\{(x,y,c) \in S \mid x > \theta\}$.
Now you can check all plausible $\theta$ values (..,2008,2009,..,2020) to see how good your data can be seperated. For example you could use [Matthews correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthews_correlation_coefficient) to evalute which $\theta$ is best.

But If you want to see if there is some linear correlation, yes you could compute the correlation coefficient, but I would assume that there is no linear correlation. Essentially you are computing the [Point-biserial correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-biserial_correlation_coefficient).

Also with the thresholding method, in case you see that all $\theta$ perform more or less the same, and badly, you can see that there is no linear correlation.

You should have a look at histograms to see how your data is distributed.